# ActiveMQ C Client in AIX server 6.1

Tags: c++, c, activemq-classic, aix

We are trying to implement Active MQ C client in AIX Server. Having lot of compatibility issues to compile the CMS client in AIX.

Please anyone suggest me what are other possibilities to use active MQ client and Step by step it would help to solve our issue.

Server : AIX 6.1
compiler : XLC

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported ActiveMQ C or C++ client for AIX, in fact the ActiveMQ CPP client is not being actively maintained so I would suggest looking into something like a simpler STOMP client or perhaps give one of the [Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) project clients a try to see if that would work as ActiveMQ 5 has support for AMQP 1.0 as well.